# Better way to make a background slideDown with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to make the background of a webpage slideDown() a different background based on the button pressed. with jquery. Currently I have an absolute positioned background with a lower z-index than everything else, but I was wondering if there was a better way, or if this was the correct approach? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that an absolute positioned div is great for doing background slideDown. If jquery is already loaded to the page, it's the easiest way to do it. Your approach is fine/

Answer (score 0):

You could use the CSS `background-image` property (which works with gradients in newer browsers, if you find that useful) to draw the background, and have jQuery animate the `background-position` property to slide it down.

Here is a live demo of it: http://jsfiddle.net/fD8WJ/ (Firefox-only for the gradient effect, but it will work with any `url(...)` image). It uses a small jQuery plug-in to address jQuery's lack of support for specifying multiple values for `background-position` in `jQuery.animate()`. Otherwise, it's quite snazzy.

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117594/adding-amount-to-background-position-on-click-jquery/2117629#2117629

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, I may have caused confusion with how I stated the question. What I as looking for was the lifting of the mask of a different background in a slideDown fashion, not the actual background sliding down.